# form not redirecting or sending email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Having an issue with my mailer script. When an email is sent it doesn't redirect to my chosen page it sits on `mail.php` which os the logic file. Having some issues understanding what the top section is asking me for too.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
require 'c:\php\includes\PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.website.com'; // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'my@website.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                         // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->From = 'http://iamdanbarrett.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Contact Form';

$mail->addAddress('iamdanbarrett.com');               // Name is optional


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'General Enquiries';

$mail->Body    = "<html><body>Name: " . $_POST["Name"] . "<br><br>Email: " . $_POST["Email"] . "<br><br>Message: " . $_POST["Message"];

// $mail->Body    = 'Details below:<br><hr><br><br><b>Shortlist:</b><br>' . $_POST["strShortlist"] . '<br><br><b>Company:</b> ' . $_POST["strCompany"] . '<br><br><b>Full Name:</b> ' . $_POST["strFullname"] . '<br><br><b>Email:</b> ' . $_POST["strEmail"] . '<br><br><b>Contact No:</b> ' . $_POST["strContactNo"] . '<br><br><b>No of People:</b> ' . $_POST["strNoOfPeople"] . '<br><br><b>Start Date:</b> ' . $_POST["strDate"] . '<br><br><b>Requirements:</b> ' . $_POST["strRequirements"] . '<br><br><b>Other:</b> ' . $_POST["strOther"] . '<br><br><b>Salesperson:</b> ' . $_POST["strSalesperson"];

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo '';
   echo '';
   exit;
} else {

}

?>

</head>

<body>

<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://iamdanbarrett.com/;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: into the else {}, use this: `header('location: http://iamdanbarrett.com/');` Anyway, you have a syntax error on your javascript: `window.location.href = "http://iamdanbarrett.com/;` missing `"` after `.com/`, which is possibly mostly why your script isn't redirecting. Anyway, I would rather use PHP's `header` for such a job instead of javascript.

Comment: Just a note for future, don't include things that can be used to personally identify you, or your website URL when asking for help regarding code. You have shown your code, which highlights any vulnerabilities and then told any malicious person spotting them, where to go to exploit them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you have to bring Javascript in here ? Use the PHP's `header()` instead.

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
        die("Mail was not sent!");
} else {
    header("location:http://iamdanbarrett.com/");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php header function. Put below code in your else part.

```
header("Location:http://iamdanbarrett.com/");exit;
```

Comment: How is it different from previous answer?

Comment: both answers having post time difference in seconds.. :)

Comment: You answered 33 seconds later)))